# Removing '\n' from a string sends additional characters to front of line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure if this is a common problem or not, but I haven't been able to find anyone with something similar going on.
Basically what has happened is I've taken a bunch of strings from a file and sorted them all into separate variables- that's all working fine. 
When I go to print it, though, using this:

```
print eventlist[i][1] + " to " + eventlist[i][2] + " | " + eventlist[i][3] + eventlist[i][4]
```

I get an output on several lines instead of just one:

```
12:30AM to 1:30PM | ECS 124
CSC 360
```

I've tried to strip off the `\n` character off `eventlist[i][3]` and in theory it works fine, but it sends everything after it in the print line to the front of the line, overwriting what's already there:

```
location = eventlist[i][3].rstrip("\n")
print eventlist[i][1] + " to " + eventlist[i][2] + " | " + location + eventlist[i][4]
```

becomes:

```
CSC 360 to 1:30PM | ECS 124
```

Instead of:

```
12:30AM to 1:30PM | ECS 124 CSC 360
```

I have also tried stripping the last character from the line as it was read (`location = line[9:-1]`) but that gave me the same issue

I've been able to narrow down the exact issue but I haven't been able to find any way to fix it. I'm new to python and I've been googling for hours. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This seems wrong....can you put up an example `eventlist`?

Comment: Smells like Windows vs Unix line ends. You did not tell us how you read these strings from file.

Comment: Try wrapping the offending section with `repr`, i.e. `repr(eventlist[i][3]`, to see what else might be hiding in there causing problems. Like pburka said, it's probably `\r` characters, but this is how you could find out yourself.

Comment: use the .strip() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input probably has `\r` characters in addition to `\n` characters. These special characters date back to the days of teletype machines, essentially automatic typewriters. The `\r`, or return, instructs the teletype to return the carriage to the beginning of the line, and `\n`, or new line, instructs the teletype to advance the platen to the next line. You removed the new line character, and your terminal (semi) faithfully emulates a teletype machine, and overwrites the current line. On a real teletype you'd overwrite the original text, and if you did this enough times you'd probably wear right through the paper. But on your video terminal (VT) it just replaces the characters which were previously there.

To fix this, you should also strip the `\r` characters.

Comment: or just use `strip()` with no arguments

Comment: Worked instantly!!! Thank you so much! I had no idea \r was even a thing. I'll be sure to watch for it in the future!

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
print "{0} to {1} | {2} {3}".format(*[x.strip() for x  in eventlist[i][1:5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print (eventlist[i][1].strip() + " to " + eventlist[i][2].strip() + 
       " | " + eventlist[i][3].strip() + eventlist[i][4].strip())
```